# how to retrain multiple instances of inception using tensorflow's retrain.py

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, image-recognition

I am building an app that allows a user to retrain inception through a GUI. I am currently basically going through tensorflow's image_retrain example found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining) and building a GUI as a front-end. I don't know where the actual trained neural network is stored or how to train multiple instances of it. It seems that the output_graph argument defaults to `/tmp/output_graph.pb` but I don't know if that is the trained network itself or something else (I don't know a lot about tensorflow). I also want everything to be stored only within the directory my app runs from. I am also currently cloning the entire tensorflow github repository and I'm wondering if all I need is the `retrain.py` file and the `label_image.py` file.  Here are my questions:
1. What is the output graph?
2. How do I store multiple instances of retrained inception that are each trained for specific sets of categories?
3. Do I need to clone the whole repository?
I am running on windows with python 3.5.2 64 bit and tensorflow version 1.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. the output graph *is* where the network itself is stored
2. make a directory for your instance of inception. create a bottleneck directory inside the main directory. use the additional arguments `--output_graph /path/to/main/dir/output_graph.pb --bottleneck_dir /path/to/main/dir/bottleneck_dir --output_labels /path/to/main/dir/output_labels.txt` when you run `retrain.py`.
   Then, when you run `label_image.py`, you should have additional arguments that look like this: `--graph /path/to/main/dir/output_graph.pb --labels=/path/to/main/dir/output_labels.txt` and the other arguments that you would have used based on the [tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining)
3. No, you only need `retrain.py` and `label_image.py`